# Not able to read one particular XML node using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using PHP to parse an XML file, and am successfully able to pull data from the file, with the exception of one particular node. There is an open ended tag labeled "ImageData" followed by a block of text. The block of text is not getting picked up, and I can't figure out why its ignoring the text that follows the "ImageData" tag.

Here's the relevant XML code:

```
<Part>
<Figure>
<ImageData src="images/interbank_img_0.jpg"/>
The text I want is here
</Figure>
```

This is the PHP script:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("rates/interbank.xml");
$test = $xml->Part[0]->Figure[0];
```

Here's the result when outputting $test:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  ["ImageData"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["src"]=>
      string(26) "images/interbank_img_0.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That `ImageData` tag isn't "open-ended", it's self-closing.

Comment: According to some comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php you apparently need to do some extra stuff to access text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the node to string

```
<?php
//$xml = simplexml_load_file("rates/interbank.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo><Part>
<Figure>
<ImageData src="images/interbank_img_0.jpg"/>
The text I want is here
</Figure></Part></foo>');

echo $xml->Part[0]->Figure[0]; // echo casts the "parameters" to string before printing
```

prints

```
The text I want is here
```